# FullPage.JS split screened. On mobile device make it one page style

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive, fullpage.js

I've found a [great example](https://www.antimath.info/jquery/using-fullpage-js-to-make-a-vertical-split-screen-parallax/#comment-314945) of a split screen functionality in FullPage.js library. Here is a [demo](https://www.antimath.info/demos/split-screen/).

Here I've made a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/13sqvr5k/) with one exception, it's not a fullscreen.

```
#splitscreen > .section .column-left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
}

#splitscreen > .section .column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

#splitscreen > .section .column-left {
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#splitscreen > .section .column-right {
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#splitscreen > .section.active {
  z-index: 1;
}

#splitscreen > .section.active .column-left {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#splitscreen > .section.active .column-right {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

#splitscreen > .section.active ~ .section .column-left {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

#splitscreen > .section.active ~ .section .column-right {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

/* prevent fullpage from translating the page */
#splitscreen {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
}

#splitscreen > .section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

But the question is how to modificate the original code in order to make a FullPage.js work in default slide state? In other words, once a mobile device is detected (media query) force FullPage.js to the one page style.

**UPD**:
I've added this JS and CSS to destroy the FullPage config once mobile device is detected. But it works purely on CSS. How I can reinitiate it on mobile with one page style?

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    'use strict';

    var fullPageCreated = false;
    createFullpage();

    function createFullpage() {
        if (fullPageCreated === false) {
            fullPageCreated = true;
            $('#splitscreen').fullpage({
                scrollingSpeed: 1000,
                responsiveWidth: 740,
                verticalCentered: false,
                anchors: [''],
                navigation: true,
                navigationPosition: 'left',
                css3: true,
                scrollingSpeed: 800,
                autoScrolling: true,
                fitToSection: true,
                fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
                scrollBar: false,
                easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
                easingcss3: 'ease',

                keyboardScrolling: true,
                animateAnchor: true,
                recordHistory: true
            });
        }
    }

function createFullpageMob() 
   {         

        $('#splitscreen').fullpage({
            scrollingSpeed: 100000, /*for debug purpose*/
            responsiveWidth: 500,
            verticalCentered: false,
            anchors: [''],
            navigation: false,                
            css3: true,
            scrollingSpeed: 10800, /*for debug purpose*/
            autoScrolling: true,
            fitToSection: true,
            fitToSectionDelay: 1000,
            scrollBar: true,
            easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
            easingcss3: 'ease',

            keyboardScrolling: true,
            animateAnchor: true,
            recordHistory: true
        });

}  

    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 400) {
        $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 400) {
            createFullpage();
        } else {
            if (fullPageCreated == true) {
                fullPageCreated = false;
                $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
                createFullpageMob();/*seems that it's initizlized, but doesn't work*/
            }
        }

    });


});
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 420px) {

    #splitscreen > .section .column-left {

        width: 100%;
    }

    #splitscreen > .section .column-right {

        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could consider using [multiScroll.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/) (same author) and then use the [Responsive  Expand extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/multiScroll/extensions/responsive-expand.html) to turn both sides into a single full width section.

Comment: I've made some adjustements with `destroy` function. But now I don't know how to properly reinitiate `FullPage` on mobile device... I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have sorted it by now, but what I would do is add a class on say body and use it as a name space for all your split screen fullPage modifications. So this way when the class is removed from body, your split screen styles are no longer active and have effectively reverted back to original fullPage behaviour.